# Using an array to track which dice were used in the calculation of the score

Tags: c++, arrays, output

I'm using the array diceUsed in GetScore to check to see if a dice was used to add to the total score. If it does add, the output for the dice should have "-" around it (ex. Roll 1: -1- 3). However the output of  my code is not generating correctly. In the bottom of my GetScore function, I run a loop which checks to see if the score has changed with the input of a dice. However it appears to be wrong. What logic must be changed in the loop to create a properly functioning output? At the very bottom of my code is the generated and expected outcome.

```
int scoring[7][7] =
{
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 100, 200, 1000, 2000, 4000, 8000},
    {0, 0, 0, 200, 400, 800, 1600},
    {0, 0, 0, 300, 600, 1200, 2400},
    {0, 0, 0, 400, 800, 1600, 3200},
    {0, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 2000, 4000},
    {0, 0, 0, 600, 1200, 2400, 4800}

};

int GetScore (int * dice, int * diceUsed, int numRead)
{
    // Initialize variables
    int score = 0;
    int straight = 1;
    int pairs = 0;
    // Array to hold which pips were rolled
    int pipCount[7] = {};
    // Loop through a set of rolls and record the number of times a
    // certain  die number was rolled
    for (int i = 0; i < numRead; i++)
    {
            // Set number to equal a die rolled
            int number = dice[i];
            // Add 1 to the pipCount array in the slot of that roll
            pipCount[number]++;
    }
    // Score for straight and pairs, i set to 1 due to first number
    // being the number of rolls
    // pst
    for (int i = 1; i <= numRead; i++)
    {
            if (pipCount[i] == 2)
                    pairs++;
            if (pipCount[i] == 0)
                    straight = 0;
    }
    // Check to see if a straight or 3 pairs were found
    if (pairs == 3)
    {
            for (int i = 1; i <=6; i++)
            {
                    diceUsed[i]++;
            }
            return 500;
    }
    if(straight == 1)
    {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
            {
                    diceUsed[i]++;
            }
            return 1000;
    }
    // Checks the position in the scoring array and adds the number in
    // that position to the score, loops through the set num of rolls.
    // Also checks to see if a die added to the total score and also adds
    // one to the array if it was.
    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
    {
            int scoreChange = score;
            score += scoring[i][pipCount[i]];
            if (score > scoreChange)
                    diceUsed[i]++;
    }
    return score;
}
void WriteDiceInfo (ostream & output, int * dice, int * diceUsed, int numRead, int numRoll)
{
    int score = 0;
    score = GetScore (dice, diceUsed, numRead);
    output << "Roll " << numRoll << ":";
    for (int i = 0; i < numRead; i++)
    {
            // output << "BOOM" << ' ' << diceUsed[i+1];
            if (diceUsed[i+1] >= 1)
            {
                    output << " -" << dice[i] << "-";
            }
            else if (diceUsed[i+1] == 0)
                    output << ' ' << dice[i];
    }
    output << " ==> ";

    if (score == 0)
            output << "Farkle!";
    else
            output << score;
    output << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i <=6; i++)
    {
            diceUsed[i] == 0;
    }
}

Generated Output:
Roll 1: -4- -1- -6- -3- -2- -5- ==> 1000
Roll 2: -1- 1 6 1 1 4 ==> 2000
Roll 3: 4 -2- 4 -4- 2 2 ==> 600
Roll 4: -6- 1 6 3 6 ==> 700
Roll 5: -2- -4- -2- -4- -1- -1- ==> 500
Roll 6: -3- 1 ==> 100
Roll 7: 3 4 3 4 6 2 ==> Farkle!

Expected Output:
Roll 1: -4- -1- -6- -3- -2- -5- ==> 1000
Roll 2: -1- -1- 6 -1- -1- 4 ==> 2000
Roll 3: -4- -2- -4- -4- -2- -2- ==> 600
Roll 4: -6- -1- -6- 3 -6- ==> 700
Roll 5: -2- -4- -2- -4- -1- -1- ==> 500
Roll 6: 3 -1- ==> 100
Roll 7: 3 4 3 4 6 2 ==> Farkle!
```

Comment: If you step through your code with a debugger and keep track of what a variable should be vs what is actually is, you should be able to find what isn't working and ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first mistake is at the second loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numRead; i++)
{
        if (pipCount[i] == 2)
                pairs++;
        if (pipCount[i] == 0)
                straight = 0;
}
```

The condition of the loop must be `i <= 6`. You are looping through the numbers on a dice, not through the dices.

The second mistake is just like the previous one, in this part:

```
if (pairs == 3)
{
        for (int i = 1; i <=6; i++)
        {
                diceUsed[i]++;
        }
        return 500;
}
```

You are looping through the numbers on a dice instead of the dices themselves. It should be something like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numRead; i++)
{
        if (pipCount[i] == 2)
        {
                diceUsed[i]++;
        }
}
```

And the loop just below this one also has the same mistake:

```
if(straight == 1)
{
        for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
        {
                diceUsed[i]++;
        }
        return 1000;
}
```

I don't know what "straight" is exactly, but I guess that this should be changed to something like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numRead; i++)
{
        diceUsed[i]++;
}
```

You have also made the same mistake in the last loop of your `WriteDiceInfo`.

These were the things I found reading once through the code.

A few tips I think you can find in handy:

1. Use your arrays zero-based. I mean use your arrays from element "0" to element "n - 1" (where "n" is the length of the array, the number you write when defining it). It can be difficult at fisrt, but it will solve lots of confusions.
2. When you are using a one-based array (arrays that usually have length of "n + 1", and element from "1" and "n" are used), make your for loop one based to decrease the confusion. Write `for (int i = 1; i <= numRead; i++)` instead of `for (int i = 0; i < numRead; i++)` (like the first loop of your `WriteDiceInfo`).
3. When a function is named `WriteDiceInfo`, it should just WRITE the info. Getting the info and clearing it out should be of some other thing's duty. You could make it get as its input these: `ostream & output, int * dice, int * diceUsed, int numRead, int score`, and write out the output. And the approx. five lines of using and clearing out can be in the main, or any other function wanting to use these. Your code is more maintainable this way.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to break this down for me. I'll definitely try and use those tip you provided to create a better program.